# How to make our animation not to carry out at the beginning, only after clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I want that animation to make it after clicking the menu button. I tried `if` and `function`, but it didn't work out. [Click here for code](https://codepen.io/jarek-babiak/pen/GRpWeXy)

Comment: You need your code to be part of the Question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

You need to move your `menuAnim` code into a `click` listener.

https://codepen.io/nisharg/pen/abvJxKL